# image magnifier - zoom image on hover and pan image on mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger, zooming

I found a good example here but I had no idea how to use the code.
First, I tried the code in Blogger, nothing showed.
Second, I tried the code in jsfiddle, nothing showed too.
Third, I exported the code and pasted it in Blogger, nothing showed. >:(
The code only works when I use the exported `.html` and the online sample.
http://codepen.io/ccrch/pen/yyaraz

Does Blogger not support the code or do I use it wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to include [jquery](https://jquery.com/)?
This code depends on the Jquery javascript framework.

Simply include the jquery script above the script like so:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/yourScriptHere.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried to import all the scripts and styles, the code in Blogger and jsfiddle is not working. I also tried to put them in `header` and `body` tags. None of them show a preview image.

Comment: "all the scripts" what do you mean by that? Here is a jsfiddle with the exact same code: https://jsfiddle.net/a9rs4aza/ Your problem is that you need to attach a extra javascript framework called jquery. Here is a guide if you're still stuck: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: I meant scripts used in the exported `.html`, `.css`, `.js` files and some online style sheets, javascript files. EDIT: I have imported that file you mentioned, but it doesn' t work for me?!

Comment: @BlitZz I'm having some trouble too, is there anything blatantly obvious you can see wrong with my code?

view-source:http://www.thegodtier.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You must also place script tags to open and close the script. The JS code on the CodePen link does not include those tags.

Script opening and closing tags look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

In between those tags, you'd copy and paste the JavaScript from CodePen i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.tile')
// tile mouse actions

and so on...

</script>
```

Also copy and paste this link to the latest jQuery script, as BlitZz mentioned:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

If after doing that, the image does not zoom, please paste a link to your live page.